# How to actually download the attachment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm using urllib2 to (try to) download a file from a web site. The file can only be downloaded after specifying some form fields. I can create the request and get the response without any problem, like this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

When I look at the response headers like this `print response.info()['Content-Disposition']`, I see the file there, i.e. it prints something like `attachment;filename=myfile.txt`

But how do I actually *download* the attachment?  If I do `response.read()` I just get a string containing the HTML of the page at url. The point is that url is not a file, it is a web page with an "attachment" and I'm trying to download that attachment with urllib2. I believe the attachment is dynamically generated, so it's not just sitting there on the server.

Comment: check whether there is `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=...` or whether the page uses javascript to redirect.

Comment: Yeah, I actually checked all the javascript on the page really carefully.  I didn't find anything relevant that was actually executed upon page load.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I wasn't sending all the necessary headers.  In particular, it was important that I send the right cookies in the request headers.  I did the following:

1. Open up Chromium (or Chrome) and hit Ctrl+Shift+I to open up the developer tools.
2. Click "Network"
3. Visit the page where the file is to be downloaded.
4. Click the newly created entry in the developer tools and click Headers.  That's where I got all the info on the headers I needed to send.